# How to sum/add total to Row groups expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a row group in SSRS that calculates totals for some organization. Organizations divided into two group on specific condition. I need to calculate total of totals or just sum all cells values in row group.

[image]

Final total should be placed in spaces marked yellow.

[image: Part of our report]

Is it possible? Maybe I should use some script to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very possible to do with SSRS and the feature that you are looking for is a grouping header row:

When creating the "Organization Type" group, select "Add group header" and you will have the additional row created for you. Like this:
[image]

If the group is already created, you can right click on the organization type cell and insert a row inside the group:

[image]

Once you have the row created, you just need to add another SUM cell and the sum of that group will be calculated:

[image]